# OpenCV+Python face detector change rectangle size (25% bigger)

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, rectangles

I want to change the rectangle size of this face detector i need it about 25% bigger:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# Read the input image
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
# Draw rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
# Display the output
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

xml: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Just a plain _I don’t know how to do it_ isn’t what we expect to hear on Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Do you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: i tried with padding but with padding i cant specify percentages..

Comment: You can calculate what those percentages add up to in terms of number of elements, but it would be good if there were another way.

Comment: `25%` bigger in terms of area or length/breadth ?